# Beautifulsoup scraping multiple pages

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through multiple pages to pull indeed's company ratings.  Any ideas???  Here is the what I've done to pull one page worth of data.

```
def parse(base_url):
base_url = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Google/reviews', timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(base_url.content, 'lxml')
containers = page_content.findAll('div', {'class':'cmp-review-container'})
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['rating', 'rating_title', 'rating_description',
                     'rating_pros', 'rating_cons'])
for item in containers:
    try:
        rating = item.find('div', {'class': 'cmp-ratingNumber'}).text.replace('\n', '')
    except:
        rating = None
    try:
        rating_title = item.find('div', {'class': 'cmp-review-title'}).text.replace('\n', '')
    except:
        rating_title = None
    try:
        rating_description = item.find('span', {'class': 'cmp-review-text'}).text.replace('\n', '')
    except:
        rating_description = None
    try:
        rating_pros = item.find('div', {'class': 'cmp-review-pro-text'}).text.replace('\n', '')
    except:
        rating_pros = None
    try:
        rating_cons = item.find('div', {'class': 'cmp-review-con-text'}).text.replace('\n', '')
    except:
        rating_cons = None
    df = df.append({'rating': rating, 'rating_title': rating_title, 'rating_description': rating_description,
                         'rating_pros': rating_pros, 'rating_cons': rating_cons}, ignore_index=True)
return df
```

Comment: You mean use the page links at the bottom to get more? It looks like they just append a ?start= parameter to the URL, so I guess you could just generate that yourself?

Comment: Yep, I see from their HTML they simply add 20, 40, 60, 80, etc.. for each "next" page.  How do I adjust my code to scrape data from all the pages?

Comment: base_url = 'https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Google/reviews?start='

all_reviews_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['rating', 'rating_title', 'rating_description',
                         'rating_pros', 'rating_cons'])

num_reviews = 20 

while num_reviews < 1480: 
    
    full_url = base_url + str(num_reviews)  
    
    get_url = requests.get(full_url, timeout=5)  
        
    partial_reviews_df = parse(get_url)   

    all_reviews_df = all_reviews_df.append(partial_reviews_df, ignore_index=True)  
    
    num_reviews += 20